# Body weight readjustment (post-(exercise fat burn))

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight

A friend of mine told me you burn fat on one area of the body, and then the body weight readjusts itself so as to maintain the same proportions within a week or ten days or so of you quitting the exercise routine. However, someone on this Stack Exchange group mentioned that this is false?

Is the original claim/conclusion true or false?

Thanks.

Comment: As I had indicated....reference [Wheelchair users (including levers-powered) and losing weight](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/wheelchair-users-including-levers-powered-and-losing-weight)

Answer (score 5):

> you burn fat on one area of the body

This alone is already [false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_reduction), thus the entire statement is false.

You cannot spot-reduce fat. Either you lose it everywhere, or not at all.

Comment: Quite interesting. I was not aware of the existence of the term "spot reduction" to refer to this misconception. I would say many TV commercials (such as the one called "Extreme Power Belt", which targets the abs and back), still use this spot reduction argument to attract clients. Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington they definitely do, the only way to spot-reduce fat deposits is with a blowtorch. Just have to make do with losing weight until you are satisfied like everyone else.